# How to Hide and Show UI Grid with Columns based on input

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using Angular UI Grid. I want to show UI Grid based on checkbox input. I am able to hide and show grid based on checkbox but never able to show columns in UI Grid.

**HTML Code**

```
<table>
   <tr>
    <td valign="top">
         <label>Recursive</label>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td valign="top">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="eventadd.md_eventrecursive"
                 ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false">
    </td>
   </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<div ng-show="eventadd.md_eventrecursive">
   <div ui-grid="gridRecursiveEvent" class="gridSmallStyle"></div>
</div>
```

**JS Code**

```
$scope.gridRecursiveEvent = {
    columnDefs: [
        {
            field: 'Name', displayName: 'Name'
        },
        {
            field: 'Id', displayName: 'Id',
        },
    ],
}
```

When Recursive event is checked then it showing Grid but with no Columns

[image]

Need your help.

Comment: `<div>` elements are not allowed content of `<tr>` elements. See [MDN `<tr>` element HTML reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr).

Comment: Edited my code. <table></table> ended before <div>. Still the problem persists.

Comment: Please refer to [this page](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20108%20Hidden%20Grids). Problem is the grid is not rendered at first (since it is hidden). Checking the checkbox does not render the ui-grid. See documentation for possible workarounds that suit your wishes.

Comment: @Remko - Your suggestion is correct. Adding width and height to UI Grid solved my problem. Everything else was correct. You can put this as an answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [this page](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20108%20Hidden%20Grids).

Problem is the grid is not rendered at first (since it is hidden). Checking the checkbox does not render the ui-grid.

See documentation for possible workarounds that suit your wishes.